# Page not reachable

Tags: html, url, encoding, typo3

I have a website containing some links, which I just cannot reach. The page is multi-lingual, and I can access said pages in every language except Czech.

[Here](http://www.heco.de/cz/uslechtila-ocel/fitinky-z%C3%A1vitov%C3%A9/%C5%A1rouben%C3%AD/ploch%C3%A9-t%C4%9Bsn%C4%9Bn%C3%AD/pn-50/%E2%80%9Ecoulov%C3%A1%E2%80%9C-p%C5%99evle%C4%8Dn%C3%A1-matka/s-p%C5%99ipojen%C3%ADm-na-hadici.html) is an example of this page.

If I click on the first link on the left side of the page "vnější závit / hadicová koncovka", it returns a "bad request". However the link should be valid, since it'S generated by TYPO3. I can even access the page by using the id of the relevant page. However, I can not access the page by link, and I have no idea why. So I would be thankful for any hints. The URL should be encoded correctly. Any advice?

Regards,
Martin

Comment: Czech user here. Page normally loaded in Chrome, firefox and Safari.

Comment: @PavelJanicek: have you tested just the page only, given by the link, or also the links on that page (which does not work for me: I get a 404)

Comment: if I click on the czech page on the measure link I end on the (german) 404 page. If I go to the measure page in germany and click on translation to czech I get a 400 Bad request. there are different URls. but both URLs are longer than 260 characters. maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ I clicked all links in left menu on that page. All loaded properly. Google Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision 3cf8514bb1239453fd15ff1f7efee389ac9df8ba-refs/branch-heads/3071@{#820}
OS Mac OS X

Comment: @PavelJanicek: it's not the left menu, it's the links in the middle `"Rozměry a hodnoty"`

Comment: I would assume a problem of character coding/decoding. Have you tried whether your links work without realurl? for further inspecting urls I wrote [page_params](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/page_params)

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ the link `"Rozměry a hodnoty"` does not work for me either

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the quick answers! Thank you especially for clearing up that not the initial page I posted is the main concern (no sense in paste a link to a 404 page, huh?), but most links on that page.
@Bernd Wilke πφ: I can access the page correctly by deactivating URL Rewriting. This is what I meant by ID. We don't use RealUrl, but CoolUri, but it pretty much achieves the same thing.
I will look furhter into character length, though. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: For anyone else running into this problem:
The TYPO3 database tables `link_cache.url` and `link_oldlinks.url` were limited to 255 characters. Increasing these values solved the problem.
@BerndWilkeπφ: Since you pointed me in the right direction, I'll set your answer as solution, if you'd be so kind as to write one. Feel free to use my text above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I go to the measure page in germany and click on translation to czech I get a 400 Bad request. there are different URls. but both URLs are longer than 260 characters. This could be the problem:

The TYPO3 database tables link_cache.url and link_oldlinks.url were limited to 255 characters. Increasing these values will solve the problem.